# can zend_file_transfer_adapter_http receive additional parameters(text)?

Tags: php, file, zend-framework, file-upload

I've a situation where I have to upload file and send an ID(text/number type) to the server. If I use `zend_file_transfer_adapter_http`, can I able to get the ID along with file in the server side?

Comment: you can use a hidden field for that. get the data from the post data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_http is for uploading files only. If you need to pass other data as well, you still can but by using hidden input fields.

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
if ($request->isPost()){
    $id = $request->getPost('id');

    // Do whatever you need to do with the file and id
}
```